# Cast to specific class dynamically

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So what i need to do is the following:
I have to load some Entities (I don't know exatctly which one), change always the same property and write it back to the database.

Here is a little example what i mean:

```
public static void DoSomething(Type table)
{
    using (var db = new Entities())
    {
        var temp = db.Database.SqlQuery<table>("SELECT * FROM " + table.Name).ToList();
        if (temp.Any())
        {
            foreach (var obj in temp)
            {
                ((table)obj).SomeProp = 1;
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

`table` represents the name/type of the table.
Now how is it possible to load Entities of this type, change some properties and write it back to database if i don't know the exact class?

Edit: All those classes are generated by the Entity Framework.

Comment: You seem to know that there is a property of a specific name. How do you know this? Do all those classes derived from the same base or implement the same interface?

Comment: No, these are all different classes. It's an old "grown" database. But i KNOW that there is this property ;-)

Comment: Either use an interface (best option) or reflection (not so good option).

Comment: `table` is an object reference. You cannot use it as a type argument or in a cast expression the way you do. Maybe you want `public static void DoSomething<TTable>() { ... }` instead?

Comment: You can use a partial class and implement the interface there, this should work.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen but then i have to implement this partial class for every class i want to update this way, no?

Comment: Correct, but that would be the best way. It's best to go for the explicit route in cases like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only using `dynamic` don't work with `Entity Framework`, the changes to the Entity are not recognized by the `context`.
So I had to change the `EntityState` of the Entity manually.
Also I had to add a `class constraint` to `TTable`, because else it is not recognized as reference type.

Here the whole code:

```
public static void DoSomething<TTable>(string table) where TTable : class
{
    using (var db = new Entities())
    {
        var temp = db.Database.SqlQuery<TTable>("SELECT * FROM " + table).ToList();
        if (temp.Any())
        {
            foreach (var obj in temp)
            {
                ((dynamic)obj).SomeProp= 1;
                db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the dynamic feature of C#:

```
foreach(var obj in temp)
{
    ((dynamic)obj).SomeProp = 1;
}
```

If a property with the name 'SomeProp' does not exist, the code will throw an exception.

Comment: I already tried that, but with this i even can't load the Entities from database, because id i load 'dynamic' Entities, these are just plain objects.

Comment: You would have to cast to dynamic in the loop, not return dynamic objects from the database. This should work.

Comment: You can not save these changes with Entity Framework. Entity Framework wants Reference Types, so 'dynamic' or reflection are no possibilities.

Comment: You're not *converting* the objects to dynamic, you are only treating them temporarily in order to set that property. The object is still whatever entity object you got from the database. Both dynamic and reflection will work, if you have evidence of the contrary you need to show that code because you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot to @LasseV.Karlsen and Adrian Deac. I just got it working with a lot of combining answers. I will post an answer with the combinations!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you right, you have some objects A, B, C, D, .. which all have the property "SomeProp".

So, why dont't you create an interface like "ISomePropEntity" which has a setter / getter for this property and let all classes which have this property implement that interface.

Then you need to change your method to take a ISomePropEntity insteand of a Type object.

```
interface ISomePropEntity
{
   theType getSomeProp();
   setSomeProp(...);
}

class ImplementationClass : ISomePropEntity
{ ... }
```

And then:

```
public static void DoSomething(ISomePropEntity table)
{
    using (var db = new LiCPS_Entities())
    {
        var temp = db.Database.SqlQuery<table>("SELECT * FROM " + table.Name).ToList();
        if (temp.Any())
        {
            foreach (var obj in temp)
            {
               table.setSomeProp(...);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or add a property to the interface instead of the individual getter and setter methods. Probably better if he already has the property there.

Comment: All classes are generated from Entity Framework. I will add this to the question.

Comment: Coming from java background, but I guess you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of ways to do this:

1.If your using SqlQuery then why are you selecting something, updating it and saving it to the DB instead of updating it?

I'm not really familiar with SqlCommand(I guess there are better and safer(against SQLI) ways to do this) but I guess it should look something like:

```
using (var db = new LiCPS_Entities())
{
   db.Database.SqlCommand("UPDATE" + table + "SET SomeProp = 1 WHERE Id = 12"); 
}
```

2.Use an interface as someone suggested above.

3.Use reflection - You can update a value based on his string name.

Answer (score 0):

Modified @OblTobl code looks better for me:

```
public static void DoSomething<TTable>() where TTable : class
    {
        using (var db = new Entities())
        {
            var temp = db.Database.SqlQuery<TTable>("SELECT SomeProp FROM " + typeof(TTable).Name).ToList();
            if (temp.Any())
            {
                foreach (var obj in temp)
                {
                    ((dynamic)obj).SomeProp = 1;
                    db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you just select one property, you won't get the whole Entity. therefore you can't edit the Entity.

Comment: @ObiTobi Hm, yeah, my mistake. Anyway, generic-type-based approach looks better